# qGIS: Removing QgsPolygon(s)?

Tags: qgis

I was trying to use the lines to polygons tool in qGIS and it failed and gave me the following error:

> TypeError: setExteriorRing(self, ring: QgsCurve): argument 1 has
>   unexpected type 'QgsPolygon

It seems to do with QgsPolygons being somewhere they shouldn't be(?) Can I just remove the offending polygons somehow? How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you clean up your polygons?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When polygons' geometry is not valid, i.e. duplicates, some holes exist, self-intersections, double nodes etc. it usually may cause error when processing with *'Polygons to Lines'*. I can suggest using some QGIS's native tools to clean up your geometry, e.g. *'Check Validity'* or using [GRASS `v.clean` library](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.clean.html).